# Does the sequence $(\sqrt{n} \cdot 1_{[0, 1/n]})_n$ converge weakly in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $f_n (x) = \sqrt n 1_{[0,1/n ] } (x) \in L^2 (\mathbb R)$. Does $f_n$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L^2$?

I tried to prove it by using Hölder's inequality or the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, but neither seems to work. I also can't find a counter example. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often, the best way to establish weak convergence is a two step procedure:

1) Show that the sequence in question is bounded. In this case, this is straightforward (do it!).

2) Show that there is a dense subset $X \subset L^2$ for which
$\langle x_n, y\rangle \to \langle x, y\rangle$ holds for all $y \in X$, where $x$ is the (supposed) weak limit.

This will suffice, since for an arbitrary $z \in L^2$, we have
$$
|\langle x_n - x, z\rangle| \leq |\langle x_n - x, y\rangle| + |\langle x_n - x, y - z\rangle| \leq |\langle x_n - x, y\rangle| + C \cdot \Vert y - z \Vert \to C \cdot \Vert y - z \Vert
$$
for arbitrary $y \in X$. By choosing $y$ close enough to $z$, this shows the desired convergence.

In your case, one possible choice for $X$ is $X = L^2 \cap L^\infty$. Indeed, for $g \in L^\infty \cap L^2$, we get
$$
|\langle f_n, g\rangle| \leq \Vert g \Vert_\infty \cdot \sqrt{n} \int_0^{1/n} \, dx = \Vert g \Vert_\infty / \sqrt{n} \to 0,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you! I actually thought of this and I chose simple functions with finite measure support as the dense subset. But I haven't thought of using that the sequence is bounded in l2 and apply the holder inequality. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, this post would actually help me a lot if someone could explain the third second inequality to me. How is bounding by the norm justified ?

Comment: @Pale: Not quite sure to which inequality you are referring to. Essentially, I use that $\|x_n -x \|\leq C$ (this follows from 1)), combined with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).