# Characterization of compact operators on Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $K(H,H)$ be a linear bounded operator. Is it true that given an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_n$ if $Ke_n\to 0$ then $K$ is compact?

I know that in an Hilbert space $K$ is compact iff it is weak-strong convergent, so the question can be also expressed as:
If an operator is strong convergent on an orthonormal basis is it always weak-strong convergent?

Comment: Is there an $l^2$ sequence $(c_1,c_2,\dots)$ with $c_1+\dots+c_n = \Omega(\sqrt{n})$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **no**. For a counterexample you can take [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2859859/515871) one: on $L^2(0,1)$, define
$$Kf: x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(y)dy.$$
Consider the following orthonormal basis $e_n :=\sqrt{2} \sin(n \pi x)$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. After some calculations you get $$K e_n \to 0.$$
However $K$ is **not compact** as proved in the answers of the above link.

Comment: +1. would you mind letting me know the answer to the question I asked in the comment above? I'm curious...

Comment: +1. If $Ke_n\to 0$ for $every$ orthonomal basis $\{e_n\}_n,$ is $K$ compact?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66329/a-question-on-compact-operators